# Implementing a HashMap in C

Tags: c, data-structures, hashmap

How to go about creating a Hashmap in C from scratch as is present in C++ STL?

What parameters would be taken into consideration and how would you test the hashmap? As in, what would the benchmark test cases be which you would run before you could say that your hashmap is complete?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384359/quick-way-to-implement-dictionary-in-c

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Well if you know the basics behind them, it shouldn't be too hard.

Generally you create an array called "buckets" that contain the key and value, with an optional pointer to create a linked list.

When you access the hash table with a key, you process the key with a custom hash function which will return an integer. You then take the modulus of the result and that is the location of your array index or "bucket". Then you check the unhashed key with the stored key, and if it matches, then you found the right place.

Otherwise, you've had a "collision" and must crawl through the linked list and compare keys until you match. (note some implementations use a binary tree instead of linked list for collisions).

Check out this fast hash table implementation:

https://attractivechaos.wordpress.com/2009/09/29/khash-h/

Comment: Besides LLs and trees, you can have a hash map per bucket that uses a different hash to handle collisions.

Answer (score 7):

The primary goal of a hashmap is to store a data set and provide near constant time lookups on it using a unique key.  There are two common styles of hashmap implementation:

- Separate chaining: one with an array of buckets (linked lists)
- Open addressing: a single array allocated with extra space so index collisions may be resolved by placing the entry in an adjacent slot.

Separate chaining is preferable if the hashmap may have a poor hash function, it is not desirable to pre-allocate storage for potentially unused slots, or entries may have variable size.  This type of hashmap may continue to function relatively efficiently even when the load factor exceeds 1.0.  Obviously, there is extra memory required in each entry to store linked list pointers.

Hashmaps using open addressing have potential performance advantages when the load factor is kept below a certain threshold (generally about 0.7) and a reasonably good hash function is used.  This is because they avoid potential cache misses and many small memory allocations associated with a linked list, and perform all operations in a contiguous, pre-allocated array.  Iteration through all elements is also cheaper.  The catch is hashmaps using open addressing must be reallocated to a larger size and rehashed to maintain an ideal load factor, or they face a significant performance penalty.  It is impossible for their load factor to exceed 1.0.

Some key performance metrics to evaluate when creating a hashmap would include:

- Maximum load factor
- Average collision count on insertion
- Distribution of collisions: uneven distribution (clustering) could indicate a poor hash function.
- Relative time for various operations: put, get, remove of existing and non-existing entries.

Here is a flexible hashmap implementation I made.  I used open addressing and linear probing for collision resolution.

https://github.com/DavidLeeds/hashmap

Answer (score 5):

The best approach depends on the expected key distribution and number
of collisions. If relatively few collisions are expected, it really
doesn't matter which method is used. If lots of collisions are
expected, then which to use depends on the cost of rehashing or
probing vs. manipulating the extensible bucket data structure.

But here is source code example of [An Hashmap Implementation in C](https://web.archive.org/web/20160329102146/http://elliottback.com/wp/hashmap-implementation-in-c/)

Comment: As the later post says that we need to handle collision also. Moreover the hash implementation has a table_size which is like fixed. If we want to dynamically increase the size of the hashmap, without the programmer knowing how its done. Could you suggest something ?

Comment: Resizing the key space means changing the hash function or at least
the function's parameters and rehashing all the entries. Each differently sized map requires a different set of hash functions to maintain the desired key distribution.

Comment: The linked code was written by a student. "It’s the first datastructure I wrote in C". For some reason he added synchronization code to make it thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

There are other mechanisms to handle overflow than the simple minded linked list of overflow entries which e.g. wastes a lot of memory.

Which mechanism to use depends among other things on if you can choose the hash function and possible pick more than one (to implement e.g. double hashing to handle collisions); if you expect to often add items or if the map is static once filled; if you intend to remove items or not; ...

The best way to implement this is to first think about all these parameters and then not code it yourself but to pick a mature existing implementation.  Google has a few good implementations -- e.g. http://code.google.com/p/google-sparsehash/

Comment: While relevant for algorithms, sparsehash is a C++ implementation of a hashmap. If you're looking for pure-C prerolled hashmaps, look elsewhere.