# How to insert elements in an array without duplicate?

Tags: c

i want to make an efficient program in c that reads elements in a file and put it into an array. My idea was to have a function to look for each element if exists in the array, but it takes too long and each file has like millions of elements(duplicated). Do you have an idea of how insert these elements in the array without duplicate?

Note: these elements are numbers with 10 digits, a matrix containing the occupied places it's not an option

Comment: Is there something wrong with using a hashmap to keep track of each element already in the array?

Comment: 1) i'm using c 2) Using a hashmap has the same problem, you look one by one searching if the element its repeated, so it has the same O()

Comment: @AgustinFerrante -- *Using a hashmap has the same problem* -- No it doesn't.  if you have a map of integer and the count associated with the integer, how is that the same complexity?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie How do you associate a key to a value of 10 digits, i mean how do you search it?

Comment: I know this is `C`, but how does a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` work in C++?  It works by using key/value pairs.  Your issue has more to do with data structures and understanding them.  Making the claim that a hasmap or hash table is slow to look up a value, where you go through the keys one-by-one is totally incorrect.  Why do hash tables exist?  Not for reasons for curiousness but for real reasons, i.e. fast lookup times.

Comment: @AgustinFerrante How much about hashmaps do you know? To search for it, you using a hashing algorithm to convert the input into an output in O(1) time (ignoring collisions).

Comment: Thats the point, how do you avoid collisions. What would be a good algorithm for extremely high numbers?

Comment: You can do what you want in C, but it has the potential to be a lot of work. Are you open to using a different language that has tools to do this easily built in?

Comment: @AgustinFerrante The way it's usually done is to use modulus.  There is a lot of information on the web that explains these aspects.  The issue is that you are using a bare-bones language (C) that doesn't have hash table available.

Comment: It's for an university task, i cant use another language

Comment: @AgustinFerrante frankly it sounds like you don't understand hashmaps. It's starting to seem more like a "help I don't know how to implement a hashmap". [That's already been answered on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838404/implementing-a-hashmap)

Comment: Hashmaps have O(1) average case lookups in well implemented versions. You don't need to believe me, you [can check wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). Avoiding collisions is implementation specific, and there's many good implementations.

Comment: You could make a 10 billion element array of booleans. Set the whole array to false. Take the number from the file and use it as the index in the array. If the element is false, set it to true and store the number. If it's true, you've got a duplicate. Discard.

Comment: @AgustinFerrante It also looks like the university expected you to do independent research into hashing and hash maps.

Comment: They could also be wanting the asker to figure out resizable arrays and binary search. Get the task down to a nice, respectable O(log(N)) with some O(N) pain whenever they need to ordered-insert.

Comment: Yes, I'm believing that we're doing the OP's homework.  The question seems to be designed for the student to do the research on how to cut down the time, and not get ready-made answers here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *store all the element just once* you can use **STL** ***set*** in `c++`(a example of doing this in `c` is also given below). It store a value no more than one time. You can declare a **set** like this:

```
set<int>sett;
```

To insert a value in **set**

```
sett.insert(6);
```

To print all the value in set:

```
for(auto a: sett){
    cout<<a<<endl;
}
```

You can go to [geekforgeek](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/set-in-cpp-stl/) and [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/) website for more information.

*If you want to track a number is in array or not, you can do it efficiently like this:*

Take a **Boolean Array** or **Map** and make it's all initial value `false`. After scanning from the file, if the number is N than make the Nth index of Boolean Array or Map `true`.

Now if you want to check number M is in the array or not. You can easily get this by checking if the Mth index of Boolean array or Map is `true` or not in just O(1) time.

See the example bellow, this is done using **Boolean array**.  Remember to declear the boolean array globally if the size of boolean array is to large. You can do this by using **STL Map** too in `c++`. For learning more about **SLT MAP** visit [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/map/) , [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map), [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/map-associative-containers-the-c-standard-template-library-stl/).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool mapp[999999999] = {false};

int main()
{
    int i, n, t, m, ara[1000];
    printf("Input the size of array: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        scanf("%d", &ara[i]);
        mapp[ara[i]] = true;
    }
    printf("Input number of time you want to check a number in array or not: ");
    scanf("%d", &t);
    while(t--){
        scanf("%d", &m);
        if(mapp[m] == true)
            printf("Number Exists\n");
        else
            printf("Number Not Exists\n");

    }
}
```

You can also use this trick to don't include duplicate value in array. To do that, if the inputed number is 'a'. Check if `mapp[a]` is already marked as `true` or not. Include 'a' in array only and only is if `mapp[a] != ture`. This little change will exclude all duplicate value from your array.

```
scanf("%d", &n);
j = 0;
for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    scanf("%d", &a);
    if(mapp[a] != true){
        mapp[a] = true;
        ara[j++] = a;
    }
}
```

Comment: when I commented there are both C and C++ tag in the post. I try to help accordingly

Comment: If only you read the first few words "i want to make an efficient program *in c*" you would have been able to realize that it was in C before expending such effort

Comment: sometimes people refer c, c++, c++11, c++14, c++17 all together as c. And the two tag of the the post convinced me it will be useful if i write solution in any variant of C. Thanks for you comment i will edit the second part of my and Change it in C. Thanks again