# How to create a Map in C?

Tags: c, data-structures

I need to create a Map data type in C, just to reduce the complexity order of an algorithm.

I am trying to do something like this:

```
{
   "emma": "watson",
   "raul": "boome",
}
```

where the "key" is the name, and the "value" the surname.

Then, I have to be able to access it easily, in O(1), like this:

```
// Pseudocode
printf("%s", map.emma);
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implementing a HashMap in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838404/implementing-a-hashmap-in-c). You have a statically typed "generic" macro-based implementation in [klib here](https://attractivechaos.wordpress.com/2009/09/29/khash-h/).

Comment: [A newer version might be on GitHub](https://github.com/attractivechaos/klib).